# monero-wallet-cli Error message: refresh failed

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, mining

When I run *monero-wallet-cli * I get an error message. However, the Wallet does start.

The code is being run in a MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit terminal on Windows 10 Pro.

Another window is open running ./monerod --offline (not enough space or resources to copy a 41GB blockchain)

Copy from terminal:
#

> ./monero-wallet-cli This is the command line monero wallet. It needs
>   to connect to a monero daemon to work correctly. WARNING: Do not reuse
>   your Monero keys on an another fork, UNLESS this fork has key reuse
>   mitigations built in. Doing so will harm your privacy.
>
> Monero 'Lithium Luna' (v0.12.1.0-master-aa6850c7) Logging to
>   C:\Users\XXXXXXX\monero\build\release\bin\monero-wallet-cli.log
>   Specify wallet file name (e.g., MyWallet). If the wallet doesn't
>   exist, it will be created. Wallet file name (or Ctrl-C to quit):
>   ZuzzimWallet1 Wallet and key files found, loading...
>
> Opened wallet:
>   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXSANITISEDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
>   ********************************************************************** Use the "help" command to see the list of available commands. Use
>   "help " to see a command's documentation.
>
> ********************************************************************** Starting refresh... Error: refresh failed: internal error: Index out of bounds of hashchain. Blocks received: 0 Background refresh thread**
>   started [wallet 42X2yL]:

Questions:
1. Should I be concerned about the error message and what is causing it?

Comment: This is a bug, and one of the developers asked for repro data (ie, move your coins away and send the keys+cache files) to test a patch: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/3848. In any case, your monero are not at risk.

Answer (score 2):

See comment above. This is a bug. Coins are not at risk.